# Why does .html() method of jQuery not persist using .hover() to push HTML to container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering why in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdPry/2/ the HTML within the `<ul>` of the hovered parent item gets pushed to the container I want but on mouseleave and subsequent hovers, no HTML is pushed to the container of the same element that was first hovered. Other elements that are hovered do push the HTML in question but only once, on the first mouseover. I've copied some of the code in question below.

```
$('#superfish-1 li').hover(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.menuarea').html($('ul', this)).slideDown();
}, function() {
    // do something else
});​
```

Comment: Is your intent to _copy_ the content, or to _move_ it (meaning it's no longer in its original place)?

Comment: You're in fact moving elements into `.menuarea`, so after a while all elements are removed from their original location. You may want `.clone()`, but a better idea might be to redesign the HTML so that you don't need any moving.

Comment: @pimvdb Yes, I would like to redo the markup :) but at this point "it's just for a demo.."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing an object, you can use `html` method and pass the `html` content instead:

```
$('.menuarea').html($('ul', this).html()).slideDown();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YePWJ/